# Wordpress Iframe Center

Tags: wordpress, iframe, wordpress-theming

On my website https://www.nologo.surf/order-online/ the theme is the Uncode in Wordpress.
And i cant center the iframes...
In this Link: https://www.nologo.surf/order-online/
The iframe arent center and are not full...

And here: https://www.nologo.surf/twin/ on 360º image isnt center...

Can you help me?
Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple CSS for this iframe

```css
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

For center 360º image add this (or like inline style):

```css
#threesixty-slider-1889_HIg3ll {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But here https://www.nologo.surf/twin/ on 360º image isnt center...

Comment: Just add `display: inline-block;` to element with id `threesixty-slider-1889_HIg3ll`

Comment: I put on css, where i have to put?